# Why does a one line query bytes cost is much more than a sub query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I've got a question which is like:
*The employees who have the same branch are colleagues of each other. You need to write a query that can give you the colleagues of EmpId 'x' and the list of the colleagues should not include the user 'x' himself. For eg:- If x = 4 then the result should be EmpId 1 and 5.*

*Note: You have to write one line query which should not include any nested or sub-query.*

[image]

**Below are my answers but I'm worried about the cost of Bytes in both scenarios.**

**1. Answer using simple one-line query would be:**

```
SELECT e2.empid FROM emp e1, emp e2 WHERE e1.empid = 4 AND e1.branch = e2.branch AND e1.empid != e2.empid;
```

[image]

**2. Answer using sub-query would be:**

```
SELECT empId FROM emp WHERE branch =(SELECT branch FROM emp WHERE empId =4) and empId !=4;
```

[image]

Comment: At least because in previous query there's a hash join which costs something. The second query can calculate a `branch` and pass it as filter

Comment: Why are you worried about the bytes, they are trivial in both cases?

Comment: There's no *"bytes cost"*. "bytes" and "cost" are two different things.

Comment: I'm just worried about the memory issue if the query is having high 'bytes' than a similar query which pretty much does the same thing. Let me know if this 'bytes' is of more important in performance or memory management in any way.